# General solution of $\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x^3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the general solution of the following first order differential equation (using the integrating factor method):
$$\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x^3}$$

I found the integrating factor to be $e^{-1/x}$ meaning I would have to integrate $$\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^3}$$ and then divide through by $e^{-1/x}$ to get the general solution, but I don't know how to integrate this. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that if type expressions in the form e^abc, you achieve $e^abc$.  If you wish to have "abc" appear all in the exponent, then you should enclose the exponent in brackets.  That is, e^{abc} yields $e^{abc}$.  I have fixed this in your post, so you can view the $\TeX$ source or yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: try a substitution $x = 1/u$ in the integral.  Then $dx = -du/u^2$ and you get

$$\int dx \: \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^3} = -\int du \: u \, e^{-u}$$