# General solution of $\frac{dx}{dt} - 2tx=t^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the general solution of the following first order differential equation (using the integrating factor method):
$$\frac{dx}{dt} - 2tx=t^3$$

I found the integrating factor to be $\mathrm{e}^{-t^2}$ meaning I would have to integrate $$\frac{t^3}{\mathrm{e}^{-t^2}}$$ but I don't know how to integrate this. can anyone help?

Comment: A few helpful comments on posing questions at MSE:  1. You should never use double dollar signs in the title of a post.   2. Please see my comment (in your other recent question) about putting the exponent in brackets so that your question renders correctly.  3. It is discouraged to ask very [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309188/general-solution-of-fracdydx-fracyx2-frac1x3) back to back in such a quick manner.  Pore over the answers in your previous question, and then try and tackle this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integrating factor is correct, but your integral is off.  Multiplying by the integrating factor yields

$$e^{-t^2}x'-2te^{-t^2}x=(e^{-t^2}x)'=t^3e^{-t^2}$$

$$e^{-t^2}x=\int t^3e^{-t^2}dt$$

$$u=t^2,du=2tdt$$

$$\int t^3e^{-t^2}dt=\frac12\int ue^{-u}du=$$

$$-\frac12ue^{-u}+\frac12\int e^{-u}du=-\frac12e^{-u}(u+1)$$

$$e^{-t^2}x=-\frac12e^{-t^2}(t^2+1)+C$$

$$x=-\frac12(t^2+1)+Ce^{t^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{t^3}{e^{-t^2}}dt = \int t^3e^{t^2}dt$$
Let $u=t^2\implies du=2tdt$

Now we have:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int t^2e^udu=\frac{1}{2}\int ue^udu$$

Now integrate by parts.

If you need further help, just leave a comment.

Comment: It should be noted that I did not check the DE's portion to see if that was done correctly.  Rather, I only describe how to integrate the above fraction...

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the integrating factor comes from an observation that
$$
   t^3  = \frac{\mathrm{d} x(t)}{\mathrm{d} t} - 2 t x(t) = \mathrm{e}^{t^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \left( \mathrm{e}^{-t^2} x(t) \right)
$$
Thus the solution to the equation is 
$$
      \mathrm{e}^{-t^2} x(t) = x_0 + \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{-s^2} s^3 \mathrm{d} s = x_0 + \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{-s^2} s^2 \mathrm{d} \left( \frac{s^2}{2} \right) \stackrel{u = s^2}{=} x_0 + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{t^2} \mathrm{e}^{-u} u \mathrm{d} u 
$$
The latter integral can be integrated by parts, giving:
$$
    x(t) = \left(x_0 + \frac{1}{2} \right) \mathrm{e}^{t^2} - \frac{1+t^2}{2}
$$